# Selenium Webdriver 3.141.0 driver.Manage().Logs.AvailableLogTypes throwing System.NullReference Exception

Tags: c#, selenium, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver

After my latest Chrome update to 76 version, my Selenium code snippet to get any console logs using `driver.Manage().Logs.GetLog(LogType.Browser)` is throwing error. Notice the `Logs.AvaialbleLogTypes` is throwing `NullReference exception`. Do we need to enable any settings? Is there any other way to get console errors

I tried using `LoggingPreferences` but that returns invalid argument error and fails to open chrome driver

Comment: Which version of ChromDriver are you using? If Chrome got updated, you'll need to update your ChromeDriver as well.

Comment: i have same problem. I updated to latest chrome driver but it didn't solve the problem.

Answer (score 7):

This is my quick and dirty solution (until selenium 4 is out, where this problem is fixed) - it is working, you can refine it and add more checks and validations.

I expose it as an extension method GetBrowserLogs

```cs
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Chromium;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Remote;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Net.Http.Headers;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Text;

namespace SeleniumConsumer
{
    internal static class Program
    {
        private static void Main()
        {
            // setup options
            var options = new ChromeOptions();
            options.SetLoggingPreference(LogType.Browser, LogLevel.All);

            // do whatever actions
            var driver = new ChromeDriver(options)
            {
                Url = "https://www.yahoo.com/"
            };

            // extract logs
            foreach (var log in driver.GetBrowserLogs())
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"{log["timestamp"]}: {log["message"]}");
            }

            // cleanup
            driver.Dispose();
            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.WriteLine("Press any key to exit...");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }

    public static class WebDriverExtensions
    {
        public static IEnumerable<IDictionary<string, object>> GetBrowserLogs(this IWebDriver driver)
        {
            // setup
            var endpoint = GetEndpoint(driver);
            var session = GetSession(driver);
            var resource = $"{endpoint}session/{session}/se/log";
            const string jsonBody = @"{""type"":""browser""}";

            // execute
            using (var httpClient = new HttpClient())
            {
                var content = new StringContent(jsonBody, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
                var response = httpClient.PostAsync(resource, content).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
                var responseBody = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().GetAwaiter().GetResult();
                return AsLogEntries(responseBody);
            }
        }

        private static string GetEndpoint(IWebDriver driver)
        {
            // setup
            const BindingFlags Flags = BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic;

            // get RemoteWebDriver type
            var remoteWebDriver = GetRemoteWebDriver(driver.GetType());

            // get this instance executor > get this instance internalExecutor
            var executor = remoteWebDriver.GetField("executor", Flags).GetValue(driver) as DriverServiceCommandExecutor;
            var internalExecutor = executor.GetType().GetField("internalExecutor", Flags).GetValue(executor) as HttpCommandExecutor;

            // get URL
            var uri = internalExecutor.GetType().GetField("remoteServerUri", Flags).GetValue(internalExecutor) as Uri;

            // result
            return uri.AbsoluteUri;
        }

        private static Type GetRemoteWebDriver(Type type)
        {
            if (!typeof(RemoteWebDriver).IsAssignableFrom(type))
            {
                return type;
            }

            while(type != typeof(RemoteWebDriver))
            {
                type = type.BaseType;
            }

            return type;
        }

        private static SessionId GetSession(IWebDriver driver)
        {
            if (driver is IHasSessionId id)
            {
                return id.SessionId;
            }
            return new SessionId($"gravity-{Guid.NewGuid()}");
        }

        private static IEnumerable<IDictionary<string, object>> AsLogEntries(string responseBody)
        {
            // setup
            var value = $"{JToken.Parse(responseBody)["value"]}";
            return  JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IEnumerable<Dictionary<string, object>>>(value);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is currently broken and only fixed in the Selenium 4 alpha coming out: https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/7342

From reading the issue it appears that changes to the chromedriver necessitate changes to the .Net Selenium implementation to correct the issue.